# EditText triggers full scroll on input

Tags: android

I have some `EditText` widgets in a `TableLayout` placed in a `HorizontalScrollView`. When I touch an `EditText` field to enter some input a full scroll offscreen is triggered, away from the focused `EditText`, to the end of the `HorizontalScrollView`. This does not happen when no input type is set, only when I change to "number" or "numberDecimal", which leads me to believe it has something to do with the soft keyboard. The only thing changed, scroll event related, is in each col along the `EditText` there's a custom `SeekBar` and I had to add one line to prevent scroll intervene with its touch:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);   
        ...
}
```

In my Manifest, I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` for my `Activities`. When the scroll is triggered by the `EditText` touch, the `SeekBar` resets to default value, which does not happen with normal scroll.
Very strange, any idea why that might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57382   "We saw this problem with an EditText inside a layout which was part of a HorizontalScrollView. When the user clicks in the EditText, the entire screen was scrolled (unnecessarily) horizontally taking the EditText out of the visible screen area."

Comment: Yeah, definitely the same thing. Removing `android:gravity="center"` fixed it.:)